# Automatic SSL redirect with no extension on filename, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've been ripping my hair out over htaccess lately. Basically, I set up an automatic redirect from http to https using this. Now, I wished to add the functionality to strip off file endings (in this case .php), to simply have domain.tld/privacy, instead of domain.tld/privacy.php.

I can't get this to work properly however (rendering in 500 - Internal server error). I've looked through several threads on the no filename endings on S/O, and whilst these lines seem to work for those people, they don't for me. Could it be conflicting with the SSL rules somehow? If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be much obliged!

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mightweb\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mightweb.net/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: What URL are you going to that's causing the error? What does your error logs say?

Comment: The URL is http://mydomain.tld/about/
Even though I type /about (without the ending slash) it automatically appends the slash again. This on Chrome. This does not happen on FF. Is there any way to allow the ending slash as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your second rule (that appends the php extension) to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Works dandy! Much obliged!

Answer (score 1):

You can add that (Just below `RewriteEngine On`):

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Did not seem to produce any different results unfortunately. `mydomain.tld/privacy/` still results in a 500 server error, whilst `mydomain.tld/privacy` does not. Updated .htaccess in main post.